# Decorators plugin missing with polymer-cli

Tags: node.js, polymer, babeljs

I'm using polymer-cli (v1.9.11) to serve my project while developing it :

```
polymer-cli serve
```

But when I use decorators (@customElement) in my js sources like this :

```
import { LitElement, html, property, customElement } from 'lit-element';
import '@polymer/iron-ajax';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-combo-box';

@customElement('my-element') // HERE
class MyElement extends PolymerElement {

    static get properties() {
```

It raises this error when I request the file :

```
Error SyntaxError: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): 'decorators-legacy, decorators' (5:0)
    at Parser.raise (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:776:15)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2098:18)
    at Parser.parseDecorator (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4133:10)
    at Parser.parseDecorators (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4115:28)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3959:12)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4513:23)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4500:10)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3938:10)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:5304:17)
    at Object.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:10083:24) {
  pos: 138,
  loc: Position { line: 5, column: 0 },
  missingPlugin: [ 'decorators-legacy', 'decorators' ]
}
```

So I'm wondering where I should declare one of these plugins ?

Comment: Did you see this? https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#declare-with-decorators

Comment: @clapas Yes I've already seen this, but the problem is that I can't find where I should do this : "If you’re using Babel, you’ll need to use the @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators plugin.", I can't find where the plugin can be added ! :/

Comment: Same here. I ended up using webpack as in this example: https://github.com/JeremyBernier/lit-element-webpack-hello-world

Comment: @clapas, yep, I've also tried webpack, but if I remember correctly, it doesn't optimize the result as much as polymer-cli should, or am I wrong about this ?